# Point above or below the line

Tags: linear-algebra

I develop some program and I encountered to this problem:

[image]

We know point **P**, **X**, and angle **a**. Range of angle is <0°,360°> between lines **p** and **o**. How I can determine in which side of line **o** is point **X**? Line **p** is always  perpendicular to x axe. I thought that I would use this equation: (**Bx - Ax) * (Cy - Ay) - (By - Ay) * (Cx - Ax)** (slope) but second point of line **o** is missing and I have no idea how do this with given angle.

Comment: Change coordinates such that $P$ is the origin and $o$ is the x-axis. Then use the `atan2` function.

Comment: Can you explain me closer how I can compute this. Parameters of a tan2 is point [x,y]. Can I use [a,b] and then compare result with 0, π, -π...?

Answer (score 2):

You have two vectors: $X-P$ and $\langle \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right), \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)\rangle$.  $X$ lies below the line if and only if $(X-P) \times \langle \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right), \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)\rangle$ (when both are regarded as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with zero third coordinate) points upwards (so that the three form a right-handed system).

Comment: Thanks, I have last question. What would change if we know coordinates of vector on line o instead of point P? I mean arrow in the picture.

Comment: Nothing, really. I used the angle $\alpha$ to construct the vector; if instead you are given the vector (say $\langle \alpha_1, \alpha_2\rangle$), then you want to look at $(X-P)\times \langle \alpha_1, \alpha_2\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Equation for line $o$:
$$
u(t) = p + t q
$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with normed direction vector $q = (\sin a,  \cos a)^T$ and vector $p = (x, y)^T$. Then
$$
v = x-p
$$
where $x = (a, b)^T$ (vector $x$, not coordinate $x$; coordinate $a$, not angle $a$) and $v$ is the vector from line $o$, at the end point of $p$, to the end point of $x$.

And now we decompose $v$ into two parts:
$$
v_q = (v \cdot q) \, q
$$
is the part of $v$ in direction of $q$. Then
$$
v_\perp = v - v_q
$$
is the part of $v$ orthogonal to $o$'s direction vector $q$.
It should have a negative $y$ coordinate if $x$'s end point is below the line $o$,  if the angle $a$ is non-zero, $a \in (0, 2\pi)$.

Otherwise ($a = 0$) check if it's $x$ coordinate is positive.

#### Example

This is a vector on the line $o$:

```
octave> p = [2, 5]'
p =
  2
  5
```

Line $o$ has an $60^\circ$ angle $a$ regarding to the $y$-axis:

```
octave> a = 60 * 2 * pi / 360
  a =  1.0472
```

Vector $q$ is a normed direction vector of line $o$:

```
octave> q = [sin(a), cos(a)]'
  q =
    0.86603
    0.50000
```

This is an example vector below the line $o$:

```
octave> x = [4,3]'
  x =
    4
    3
```

Here we have the difference vector $v$ that would lead from $p$ to $x$:

```
octave> v = x - p
  v =
    2
   -2
```

This is $v_q$, the part of $v$ in direction of $q$:

```
octave> vq = (v' * q) * q
  vq =
     0.63397
     0.36603
```

And this is $v_\perp$, the part of $v$ orthogonal to $q$:

```
octave> vo = v - vq
  vo =
     1.3660
    -2.3660
```

A test:

```
octave> vo + vq
  ans =
      2.0000
     -2.0000
```

The $y$-coordinate is negative (and $a$ is non-zero):

```
octave> vo(2)
  ans = -2.3660
```

We can put the test into an octave function:

```
octave> function res = test(x)
> p=[2,5]'
> a = 60*2*pi/360
> q = [sin(a), cos(a)]'
> v = x - p
> vq = (v'*q)*q
> vo = v - vq
> if (vo(2) == 0)
> res = 0
> else
> res = vo(2)/abs(vo(2))
> endif
> endfunction
```

Some applications:

```
octave> x2 = [ -2, 7]'
octave> test(x2)
..
ans =  1
```

which means $x_2$ is above line $o$. And then

```
octave> test(p)
ans = 0
```

which means $p$ is on the line $o$.

Comment: Please can you show me example? I try to implement it but something is wrong. if X = [i1,i2] and P[j1,j2], then v = (i1 - j1, i2 - j2), q = (sin a, cos a). vq1 = j1 + (sin a * (i1-ij) + cos a * (i2 - j2)). Analogy vq2. And then compute last v1 and v2? I still can not get if point is in right or left side od line.

Comment: Thanks. There was an error: the formula for $v_q$ should not have added $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (renamed the angle as "A" to avoid confussion with the coordinate "a"): if (a-x)*tan(A)>b-y then X is below the line.